# Python: split list of filenames

Tags: python, string, list, split

this is probably a very simple question again; I've got a list of file names in a .txt file. I want to write a script that takes each filename separately and gets it from the directory. But I can't seem to split the filenames. Got an error saying 'filename too long', it tried to take all the filenames together. I tried this:

```
#lots of other stuff

resultsdir1 = "/home/blah"

barcodefile1=sys.argv[1]
barcodes1 = [f.split("/")[0] for f in open(barcodefile1)]

#blahblah

for bc in barcodes1:
    file=open(resultsdir1+"/"+bc+".csv")
```

I'm still quite new to programming, so be gentle if I made a really stupid mistake. There's lots of other stuff in the script, I really only want to know how to split the names in barcodefile1 (it's a .txt file). I'd appreciate any help!

Error message: file name too long. Then a all the names of the files separated by \t

Comment: Can you edit your post, including the entire traceback (the whole error message)?

Comment: It might also be helpful to see an example of how you want to use your script.

Comment: Also, what is the format of the files in the text file?  I'm curious why you are running `f.split('/')[0]` on each filename.

Comment: The files in the text file are csv files. I'm not sure why I'm running it either... I'm only trying to get the single filenames to fetch them from the directory.

Comment: print stuff like barcodes1 and bc to see what is going on.

Comment: We are still missing the traceback, and as well a sample file.

Comment: I tried printing barcodes1 and it doesn't find the file. I'll check the path again. Thanks for you help everybody!

Comment: Ok, the problem is that the list of filenames in barcodefile1 is not hashable. Does anybody know a way I can use the filenames in the exact order they're in?

Comment: Are the individual names in your file `barcodefile1` _tab-separated_ ? `for f in open('xyz')` only reads line by line. So, if your file is actually one big line, that will not be sufficient

Comment: Yes, they are tab-separated. I tried several things now. At the moment I keep getting the error 'file name too' long again, and then just all the filenames as a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

> Error message: file name too long. Then a all the names of the files
>   separated by \t

I take it that all the file names in your file `barcodefile1` are tab separated. Try something like the following to read such tab-separated entries. This assumes all the entries in your file are tab-separated and on *one single line*. It also assumes that your line is very large and hence tries to read the file in chunks.

```
>>> f = open('try.txt')
>>> left_over=''
>>> all_entries=[]
>>> def read_f():
...     return f.read(80)     #For very large files, you will be better off setting this to 1024 or multiples
... 
>>> for piece in iter(read_f,''): 
...     new_piece = left_over + piece.rstrip('\n')
...     new_piece_split = new_piece.split('\t')
...     all_entries.extend(new_piece_split[:-1])
...     left_over = new_piece_split[-1]
>>> all_entries.append(left_over)
>>> all_entries = filter(None, all_entries)
>>> f.close()
```

This will read your tab separated file (even if it is too big) and make a new list `all_entries`. This is analogous to your list `barcodes1`

Answer (score 0):

How about this example:

```
import os
import csv

ROOT_DIR = '/home/blah'
with open('list-of-file-names.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
      filename = "{}.csv".format(line.strip())
      with open(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR,filename)) as the_file:
          reader = csv.reader(the_file)
          for row in reader:
              print row
```

Its not clear what you mean when you say "gets it from the directory", so I assume you mean "open it and read the contents", which is what the above code does.